# glTexImage2D fail on opengles3.0 context

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I am implementing a native webgl context compatible with h5.
Currently I support webgl1.0 APIs.

On iOS I create the `EAGLContext` with `kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES3`. Other GL calls works fine, but

`glTexImage2D(3553, 0, 6408, 144, 108, 0, 6408, 5126, null), glError()=1282`

This call fails.

If I change `EAGLContext` to opengles2.0, everything works fine.

My question is all parameter values to `glTexSubImage2D` are the same. Why this call fails if I create the context as es3.0 but succeeds if the context is es2.0.

These are the gl calls dumped. The only difference is that when I create the EAGLContext using GLES3 api level, there is a glError 1282. If the context is created using GLES2 api level, everything works fine.

The first two glTexImage2D use GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, the failed one uses GL_FLOAT. But es3.0 context should support GL_FLOAT.

```
17:26:24.683200 Will setup FBOs.
17:26:24.684360 Setup FBOs done.
17:26:24.694778 glCreateTexture()=1
17:26:24.694981 glBindTexture(3553, 1)
17:26:24.695079 glTexParameteri(3553, 10242, 10497)
17:26:24.695142 glTexParameteri(3553, 10243, 10497)
17:26:24.695266 glTexParameteri(3553, 10241, 9985)
17:26:24.695313 glTexParameteri(3553, 10240, 9729)
17:26:24.695414 glTexParameterf(3553, 34046, 1.000000)
17:26:24.695414 glTexImage2D(3553, 0, 6408, 2, 2, 0, 6408, 5121, null)
17:26:24.695414 glTexImage2D(3553, 1, 6408, 1, 1, 0, 6408, 5121, null)
17:26:24.696141 [Buf:GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE:u8] 16, 16, 1
17:26:24.696961 glTexImage2D(3553, 0, 6408, 2, 2, 0, 6408, 5121, [16])
17:26:24.697674 glGenBuffers()=1
17:26:24.697862 glGenBuffers()=2
17:26:24.702478 glGenBuffers()=3
17:26:24.702547 glGenBuffers()=4
17:26:24.702675 glGenBuffers()=5
17:26:24.702734 glGenBuffers()=6
17:26:24.722429 glGenBuffers()=7
17:26:24.722589 glBindBuffer(34962, 7)
17:26:24.722697 glBufferData(34962, [65536], null, 35048)
17:26:24.722758 glGenBuffers()=8
17:26:24.722806 glBindBuffer(34962, 8)
17:26:24.722862 glBufferData(34962, [65536], null, 35048)
17:26:24.723104 createVertexArrayOES(1)
17:26:24.723690 glGenBuffers()=9
17:26:24.723743 glBindBuffer(34962, 9)
17:26:24.723799 glBufferData(34962, [2304000], null, 35048)
17:26:24.723985 glGenBuffers()=10
17:26:24.724068 glBindBuffer(34963, 10)
17:26:24.724120 glBufferData(34963, [64000], null, 35048)
17:26:24.724120 glCreateTexture()=2
17:26:24.747552 glBindTexture(3553, 2)
17:26:24.747625 glTexParameteri(3553, 10242, 33071)
17:26:24.747680 glTexParameteri(3553, 10243, 33071)
17:26:24.747733 glTexParameteri(3553, 10241, 9729)
17:26:24.747778 glTexParameteri(3553, 10240, 9729)
17:26:24.747842 glTexParameterf(3553, 34046, 1.000000)
17:26:24.747842 glTexImage2D(3553, 0, 6408, 144, 108, 0, 6408, 5126, null), glError()=1282
17:26:24.748000 glTexParameteri(3553, 10241, 9728)
17:26:24.748048 glTexParameteri(3553, 10240, 9728)
17:26:24.748120 glTexParameteri(3553, 10242, 33071)
17:26:24.748189 glTexParameteri(3553, 10243, 33071)
17:26:24.748266 glTexParameterf(3553, 34046, 1.000000)+0800
```

Comment: Does iOS even support OpenGL ES 3.0? I was under the impression that iOS support for GL ES stopped at 2.0.

Comment: Either GL_RGBA or GL_FLOAT is not supported. May be you should check the supported formats

Comment: If you are trying to call `glTexSubImage2D()`, it is expected that `glTexImage2D()` succeeded without errors, which would be rather confusing. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because JS passed invalid combination of internal format/format/type.

glTexImage2D(3553, 0, 6408, 144, 108, 0, 6408, 5126, null), glError()=1282

is actually glTexImage2D(3553, 0, GL_RGBA, 144, 108, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, null)

This combination is not valid according to https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml.

The interesting thing is that in iOS es2.0 context, this combination is valid.